# Reset Power using 555 timer

Tags: power, 555

I'm trying to cut the power for 5 seconds to my circuit every 30 minutes using a 555 timer. I've been trying to design my circuit using 555timer and NPN but im not having any luck with it has anyone got any suggestions?

Input Voltage: 5v

Comment: Show us what you have already tried on the 555. You can use the schematic editor to create a schematic. Edit your question to include circuit you have already tried.

Comment: Shouldn't need luck but like @marla says we need a circuit and an explanation of what it isn't specifically doing.

Comment: 30 minutes is 1800 seconds, so do you want a cycle to be ON for 1800 seconds and then OFF for 5, or ON for 1795 seconds and then OFF for 5?  And, how accurate does it have to be?

Comment: @EMFi: Whether the 5 seconds is part of the 30 minutes or not is less that 0.3% difference.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: You have no clue about what his application is or whether he thinks a 555 can get him 0.1%, or whatever, so why not just keep your mouth shut and watch how it plays out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evil <s>666</s> 555 timer is inappropriate for durations as long as 30 minutes.

What you want to do can be trivially done with a tiny microcontroller, like the PIC 10F200.  It has a built in oscillator that is more accurate than what a 555 can do with common parts, is smaller, takes less power, and requires no external parts other than the bypass cap.

The firmware counts ticks to get arbitrarily long time delays.  Since this is done digitally, all derived times are as good as the internal oscillator, which is a few percent.

If low power is important, then you have the PIC sleep most of the time, counting wakeups by the watchdog timer to keep time.  The watchdog isn't very accurate, but it won't drift quickly.  I've used it in low power projects where every 1000 wakeups I kept the processor on to calibrate the watchdog against the internal oscillator.  It still sleeps 99.9% of the time, and the long term accuracy is only slightly worse than the internal oscillator.  Note that a 555 with ordinary parts can't achieve that accuracy anyway, and would draw way more power.

If power isn't the issue, keep the processor running and counting instruction cycles.  At a nominal 1 M instruction cycles per second, 30 minutes only requires a 31 bit counter, so you'd use 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: Agree, although I use the 555 in a lot of circuits, its difficult to get accurate timing due to capacitor tolerance (usually 10%) and you end up having to fine-tune the resistance value which is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 555 and a CMOS logic divider (counter) -- e.g. CD4017, CD4024 or CD4026. This will allow the 555 to operate at a more practical frequency. If you run at 5 s, and divide by (1800/5 = 360, you'll be able to control your system easily.